# How to limited runner in JUnitCore.runClasses()?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have multiple class and multiple test. but when i used:

```
public class ParallelComputerExample {
    @Test
    public void runAllTests() {
        Class<?>[] classes = { Class1.class, Class2.class, Class3.class };
        JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true, true), classes);
    }
}
```

It run all @Test in the same time. I want it just create max 5 instance ?

Comment: Using `maven` framework you can specify `<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <threadCount>5</threadCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>`

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: the existing structure doesn't support that. JUnit doesn't have a way to run tests in parallel ... but under such constraints as you are asking for.

Thus: you *most likely* have to build something like that your own.

The good thing: that should be rather easy. You see, that *ParallelComputer* object you are using there is simply extending the *base* *[Computer](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/Computer.html)* class.

In that sense: go, and have a look into the source code of those two classes (you know, it is *open* source) - and then build your own extension of that *Computer* class that runs jobs in parallel, but using a limited thread pool for example.